# Configurable product not showing in frontend Even when it is stock

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database, reindex, magento2.1.5

I have some configurable products. And they are not showing in frontend. In **cataloginventory_stock_item** table **is_in_stock** is set to 1. but for some reason after reindexing in **cataloginventory_stock_status** table **stock_status** is set to 0 for some of these products. What could be the reason. Is it a bug in magento2 or I m missing something.

Answer (score 2):

I would make sure the child products 1) have a positive inventory and 2) make sure the child products are enabled for the site you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Add the associated products in the configurable product